# bad operand types for binary operator '-' with Nodes

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I am trying to create a Priority Queue with Nodes of doubly Linked List to sort the doubly linked list .
https://www.codingninjas.com/codestudio/problems/sort-a-k-sorted-doubly-linked-list_1118118?leftPanelTab=0

```
/****************************************************************

    Following is the class structure of the Node class:

      class Node<T> {
        T data;
        Node<T> next;
        Node<T> prev;

        public Node(T data) {
            this.data = data;
        }
    }

*****************************************************************/
import java.util.*;
public class Solution {
    static class compareNode implements Comparator<Node>
    {
        public int compare(Node n1, Node n2){
            return n1.data-n2.data;
        }
    }
    public static Node<Integer> sortedDll(Node<Integer> head, int k) {
        PriorityQueue<Node> pq = new PriorityQueue<Node>(new compareNode());
        /* logic goes here*/
        return head;
    }

}
```

i am getting below error when i run the above program

```
Compilation Failed
./Solution.java:21: error: bad operand types for binary operator '-'
            return n1.data-n2.data;
                          ^
  first type:  Object
  second type: Object
1 error
```

can anyone tell why i am getting this error? and how to rectify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot subtract an arbitrary object from another one

What you are actually trying to do here is to subtract one `T` from another `T`.  That is not a valid thing to do in general.  (The erasure of `T` is `Object`.)

That means that

```
static class compareNode implements Comparator<Node> {
    public int compare(Node n1, Node n2){
        return n1.data-n2.data;
    }
}
```

is not going to work.

But ... wait ... the problem actually requires your code to compare `Node<Integer>` instances rather than `Node<?>` instances.  So what you need is something *a bit like* this:

```
static class compareNode implements Comparator<Node<Integer>> {
    public int compare(Node<Integer> n1, Node<Integer> n2){
        return n1.data-n2.data;
    }
}
```

... and I think you will find that that compiles.   But it is not correct.   The correct way to write that is:

```
static class compareNode implements Comparator<Node<Integer>> {
    public int compare(Node<Integer> n1, Node<Integer> n2){
        return n1.data.compareTo(n2.data);
    }
}
```

The problem is that when you subtract one integer from another you *can* get integer overflow ... and a result with the wrong sign.

---

Another way to solve this is attempt cast the `data` values of a `Node<T>` to `Comparable<?>` and then use `Comparable.compare`.  This approach would involve some implicit and explicit runtime type checks ... and could in theory produce `ClassCastException`s.